# Synonym zen-coding and emmet

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I don't have enough points in either those tags, so I'll ask it here to bring it to the community's attention.

Zen-coding was a method to write efficiently and expand the result into HTML:

```
ul>li*4>a
```

Would be expanded to

```
<ul><li><a></a></li><li><a></a></li><li><a></a></li><li><a></a></li></ul>
```

However, the project was renamed to Emmet.

Currently we have two tags: [zen-coding](/questions/tagged/zen-coding) and [emmet](/questions/tagged/emmet). Can we please synonym those? No need to merge, as older questions still deserve their [zen-coding](/questions/tagged/zen-coding) tag. However, new questions about it should be directed to the [emmet](/questions/tagged/emmet) tag.

Comment: I didn't do this, but this has been done.

Comment: But it has been done in **a wrong way**, it's just create a tag `emmett` with 2 t ! See: [tag:zen-coding]

Comment: Completed, correctly.  All related tags synonymized to [emmet].